# How can I filter multiple query parameters with same key in Django?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-filters

I'm trying to filter multiple query parameters with a same key, for example:

*api/?city=Kazan&city=Moscow*

But I get all objects which city=Kazan

I tried this code, but nothing has changed:

```
class FinalListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = FinalSerializer
    filter_backends = [django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend]

    def get_queryset(self):
        condition = Q()
        queryset = Final.objects.all()
        city = self.request.query_params.getlist('city')


        if city:
            if city != 'all':
                for a in city:
                    condition |= Q(city__startswith=a)
                    queryset = queryset.filter(condition)

    return queryset
```

Comment: If you're using django-filters, you should use it instead of adding more conditions in `get_queryset()`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only filter at the *end* of the for loop:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    condition = Q()
    queryset = Final.objects.all()
    city = self.request.query_params.getlist('city')


    if city:
        if city != 'all':
            for a in city:
                condition |= Q(city__startswith=a)
            #                     ↓ end of the for loop
            queryset = queryset.filter(condition)

return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix indentations,

```
def get_queryset(self):
    condition = Q()
    queryset = Final.objects.all()
    city = self.request.query_params.getlist('city')

    if city:
        if city != 'all':
            for a in city:
                condition |= Q(city__startswith=a)
    
    queryset = queryset.filter(condition)

    return queryset
```